# How does the npm script in package.json 'know' where the files are (angular 2.x)?

Tags: angular, npm, package.json

I'm developing in Windows 7 on Chrome using Angular 2.4 (not using Visual Studio) and downloaded the [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html) and all is working fine.

Now, I want to see the version of 'node' I'm using, thus I type `node -v` at the command prompt in the project's folder (where the `package.json` file is) the and all is fine.

Now, I want to see the version of Typescript I'm using, thus I type `tsc -v` but it cannot find it.

If I put a script in `package.json` like `"tsc-version": "tsc -v"` and then I run `npm run tsc-version` command, I do get the Typescript version number.

How does `npm` knows where the `tsc` javascript file is?

I know it has something to do with the folder structure, and how does the  `./node_modules/.bin` folder come into play?

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Typescript installs `tsc` under the `node_modules\.bin` as part of the local installation.

`npm` appends the `.bin` directory to the shell's pre-existing path.

The `npm` [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) say this about the `npm run` script:

> In addition to the shell's pre-existing PATH, npm run adds
>   node_modules/.bin to the PATH provided to scripts. Any binaries
>   provided by locally-installed dependencies can be used without the
>   node_modules/.bin prefix. For example, if there is a devDependency on
>   tap in your package, you should write:
>
> ```
> "scripts": {"test": "tap test/\*.js"}
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> `"scripts": {"test": "node_modules/.bin/tap test/\*.js"}`
>
> to run your tests.

Outside of package.json, you would need to install `tsc` as a global dependency to use it without fully qualifying the path:

```
npm install -g typescript
```